# SQL Server Function WIthin Case Statement

Tags: sql-server

```
    select top 10 *, case     
    when datediff(day,DateOfSale, getDate())  > 5 then '5'
        when datediff(day,DateOfSale, getDate())  > 10 then '10'
... (more datediff clauses)
...
...
        else '20'
        end as jack
        from Foo
```

Is SQL Server smart enough to evaluate the `datediff` function call once within the case statement and then use that value for every `when` clause? Or is the function is getting called 'n' times, where 'n' is the amount of `when` clauses?

Comment: Regardless whether it is smart enough, you kill any index use on DateOfSale, so it is bad style.

Comment: @tomTom how would you achieve the above while perserving indexing

Comment: This usage won't disable index use since the DATEDIFF() function is a WHEN clause in the SELECT list.

Comment: Per [this blog post](http://blog.strictly-software.com/2011/10/proving-benefits-of-sargable-clauses.html), `DATEDIFF` is a non-SARGable operation, so it would be wise to create an index on your `DateOfSale` column to at least gain the ability for the optimizer to use an Index Scan.

Comment: @darthcontinent that blog post only discuss NON-Sargable operations in the where clause not the select clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to see how SQL Server could evaluate the call once.  The call has a column as parameter and so has to be evaluated for every row.

Thus, your condition is better written like:

```
when DateOfSale < dateadd(day, -5, getdate()) then '5'
```

In this case the difference is small. Date calculations are cheap.

The classic example where the function call does matter is a `where` condition on a table with an index on the date column.  For example, `YourTable` with an index on `(dt)`.  This query would allow an index to be used:

```
select * from YourTable where dt < dateadd(day, -5, getdate())
```

While this query would not:

```
select * from YourTable where datediff(day, DateOfSale, getDate()) > 5
```

Answer (score 2):

It's puzzling that so many answers are mentioning indexes. Indeed, `DATEDIFF` is not SARGable, but that's completely irrelevant here as CASE WHEN doesn't cause the query optimizer in SQL Server to consider index usage (other than trying to find a covering scannable path). The candidacy of DATEDIFF-involved expressions for index pathing is completely irrelevant to this question, as far as I can tell.

It's pretty easy to demonstrate that SQL Server does, indeed, stop evaluating predicates inside `CASE` statements once the first true predicate is found.

To demonstrate that fact, let's cook up some sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE Diffy (SomeKey INTEGER NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1), DateOfSale DATE);

DECLARE @ThisOne AS DATE;
SET @ThisONe = '2012-01-01';
WHILE @thisONe < '2013-01-01'
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Diffy (DateOfSale) VALUES(@ThisOne);
    SET @ThisOne = DateAdd(d, 1, @ThisOne);
END;
```

Then, let's `SELECT` it in the pattern of the original question. Note that the original question specifies a `TOP 10` clause without an `ORDER BY` clause, so the values we actually get back are random. But if we add a clause to the `CASE` that would poison evaluation, we can see what's happening:

```
SELECT TOP 10 *, CASE 
WHEN datediff(day,DateOfSale, getDate())  > 5 then '5'
WHEN datediff(day,DateOfSale, getDate())  > 10 then '10'
WHEN 1/0  > 1then 'boom'
ELSE '20' END
AS Jack
FROM Diffy;
```

Note that if we ever evaluated `1/0 > 1`, then we'd expect something like a `'Divide by zero error encountered.'`.  However, running this query against my server yields ten rows, all with '5' in the `Jack` column.

If we take away the TOP 10, sure enough we get some rows and then get the `Divide by zero` error. Thus, we can safely conclude that SQL Server is doing early exit evaluation on the CASE statement.

On top of it, [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) also tells us so:

> The CASE statement evaluates its conditions sequentially and stops with the first condition whose condition is satisfied.

Perhaps the question is meant to ask if the common `DATEDIFF()` subexpression is hoisted from all the `CASE` statements, computed once, and then evaluated within each predicate's context. By observing the output of `SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT ON`, I think we can conclude that's not the case:

```
   |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1004]=CASE WHEN datediff(day,CONVERT_IMPLICIT(datetimeoffset(7),[Scratch3].[dbo].[Diffy].[DateOfSale],0),CONVERT_IMPLICIT(datetimeoffset(3),getdate(),0))>(5) THEN '5'  ELSE CASE WHEN datediff(day,CONVERT_IMPLICIT(datetimeoffset(7),[Scratch3].[dbo].[Diffy].[DateOfSale],0),CONVERT_IMPLICIT(datetimeoffset(3),getdate(),0))>(10) THEN '10' ELSE CASE WHEN (1)/(0)>(1)  THEN 'boom' ELSE '20' END END END))
        |--Index Scan(OBJECT:([Scratch3].[dbo].[Diffy].[DiffyHelper]))
```

From that, we can conclude that the structure of this query means that `DATEDIFF()` is evaluated for each row and for each predicate, so `O(rows * predicates)` calls, at worst. That causes some CPU load for the query, but `DATEDIFF()` isn't quite *that* expensive and shouldn't be much of a concern. If, in practice, it turns out to be causing a performance problem, there are ways to manually hoist the computation from the query. For example, `DATEDIFF()` on the date-relative side of the comparison.

Comment: +1 Good points.  My answer mentioned sargability because that's the only place where date function evaluation has a measurable performance impact.

Comment: The CPU usage of DATEDIFF() is measurable.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, but not in your case (the expression is based on a table column value that changes for each row), but in any event, don't execute the datediff on the table column value, run a dateadd on the predicate (comparison)  value so your query can still use any existing index on DateOfSale...

```
  select top 10 *, 
      case When DateOfSale < dateadd(day, -20, getDate()) then '20'
           When DateOfSale < dateadd(day, -15, getDate()) then '15'
           When DateOfSale < dateadd(day, -10, getDate()) then '10' 
           When DateOfSale < dateadd(day, -5, getDate()) then '5' 
          else '20' end jack
  from Foo
```

Comment: Nitpick: 10 days ago is always 5 days ago.  So the conditions should probably swap places.